# Не работает limit с placeholder

Tags: sql, drupal

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  test1 (entity_id, test, created)
       SELECT entity_id, test, :c_time

       FROM test2 AS t
       WHERE entity_type = :c_repn
       GROUP BY entity_id
       LIMIT :c_start, :c_lim
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test = VALUES(test), created = VALUES(created)";

db_query($sql,$arr);
```

Как можно исправить данную проблему?

Comment: Никак, LIMIT воспринимает свои параметры как окончательные литералы и не выполняет подстановок. Изменяйте сам шаблон запроса.

Comment: делить на 3 запроса? или есть патч какой ядра? смотрел на хабре реализацию плейсхолдеров. у них работает

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10618229

Comment: Примерно понял, но как тогда доработать запрос? Сейчас смотрю ядро друпы. Но пока не знаю как переделать

Comment: Ну если устроит вынос пределов из массива параметров - можете вместо db_query() использовать db_query_range()

Comment: пробовал.  лимит не туда вставляется. на выходе выдает ошибку ибо sql  получается такого вида после конструктора

INSERT INTO  test1 (entity_id, test, created)
       SELECT entity_id, test, :c_time

       FROM test2 AS t
       WHERE entity_type = :c_repn
       GROUP BY entity_id
        
       ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE test = VALUES(test), created = VALUES(created)
LIMIT 0, 300

Answer (score 0):

А если разобраться с логикой запроса... единственное очевидное место, где может появиться дубль, чтобы сработало ODKU - это уникальный (первичный, вероятно?) индекс по entity_id. И если сработало ODKU - то entity_id не меняется, а для остальных полей Вы полностью заменяете старые значения новыми.

Но если так - то Вам нужен не `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, а [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html).

**UPDATE:**

А ещё - попробуйте тупейшее

```
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO test1 (entity_id, test, created)
        SELECT entity_id, test, :c_time
        FROM test2 AS t
        WHERE entity_type = :c_repn
        GROUP BY entity_id";
```

и выполнение через db_query_range().

Comment: по идее да. но он медленно работает. ибо сначала удаляет, а потом вставляет. в моем случае сначала идёт вставка, а потом обновление. профилировал. насчет limit у меня пока не очень с OOP.  есть такой класс abstract class DatabaseConnection extends PDO, может как то наследовать и свой дописать?  но как грамотно сделать увы, пока знаний не хватает

Comment: используются для limit abstract public function queryRange($query, $from, $count, array $args = array(), array $options = array());  и function db_query_range($query, $from, $count, array $args = array(), array $options = array()) {
  if (empty($options['target'])) {
    $options['target'] = 'default';
  }

  return Database::getConnection($options['target'])->queryRange($query, $from, $count, $args, $options);
}

Comment: как то вот так бы сделать function db_query_range2($query, $from, $count, $query_d, array $args = array(), array $options = array()) {
  if (empty($options['target'])) {
    $options['target'] = 'default';
  }

  return Database::getConnection($options['target'])->queryRange2($query, $from, $count, $query_d, $args, $options);
}  но как, я не знаю

Comment: комментария своего не увидел  - при использовании db_query_range  limit вставляется после ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

```
(int)$start .",". (int)$limit;
```

Только так, увы